# What is a good way of storing hashed passwords for easy reading/manupulation during tests

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a C# application and a database. In this database I'm storing hashed passwords and I'm wondering what the best way of doing this is?

My options appear to be either varbinary(160). The advantage of this is that binary data is a direct representation of what is inside. The disadvantage is that it's not that easy to change (trying to change the field in the database manager manually results in complaints that ntext != varbinary). Another option is to store it as string but that results in the inclusion of some very weird characters and I'm worried that it might end up containing some dangerous control characters, is this a risk? What is a good datatype?

Comment: If your hash is string compatible... then string should be the way to go. You are storing hashed passwords, so what's the worry? What "weird" characters are you seeing?

Comment: If you are really concerned, you could encode the binary to hex and store that as a varchar.

Comment: Base64 encode it and store as varchar.

Comment: It's a sha hash which results in binairy output, this can be interpeted by the ASCIIEncoding as a string but I'm not sure if that is intended?

Comment: No, you should absolutely *not* treat it as if it's ASCII - it's not. Base64 or hex are appropriate conversions.

Comment: ASCII encoding wouldn't work because it's only 7 bit and contains a bunch of control characters. See also my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822393/3558960).

Comment: It depends on which SHA you're using. SHA-1 generates a 160-bit hash value. You can store that in a CHAR(40) or BINARY(20)

Comment: Alright then I get what I should do from all of the comments. Anyone wanna post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to base64 encode it and store it in a CHAR or VARCHAR field. The value will be fairly compact (28 bytes for SHA-1) and easy to manipulate.

If a slightly larger data size is no objection, hex encoding would be a valid alternative (40 bytes for SHA-1).

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use binary datatype for storing hashed passwords.

You can use binary instead of varbinary because the hash function will always return the same number of bytes for the same type of hash (e.g. MD5, SHA1, etc.). This will cut down on the (slight) overhead required to manage a variable length binary (varbinary) column.